# AWS - Network requests from lambda inside VPC won't work for specific ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have some lambdas running inside an aws vpc that are connecting to the internet when I set their security group egress rule to allow all outbound traffic but if I change that cidr rule to a specific ip (x.x.x.x/32) instead of all traffic (0.0.0.0/0) and try to make a request to the respective host my requests time out. They are accessing the internet through a nat gateway and public/private subnets.

I've tried working the mask backwards all the way down to all traffic but only the all traffic cidr will allow me to successfully make requests.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that requested host has a security group with an inbound rule that allows traffic from CIDR block with which the lambda has been associated.

Based on your description, it looks like you allow outbound traffic from lambda but not mention the host security group rules

[image]
For example, in the image above, you have a security group for data server, and set inbound rule that allow servers to conect DB through port 5432, but also an outbound rule that allows DB to respond through 5432.

But in case of your servers security group, there's an inbound rule that allows incoming connections from DB using port 5432, but you have nothing allow to outbound, so servers will never send a request to DB.

A hole explanation of security groups are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/security-group-rules.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you think that you can add more details? Like adding a screen of the solution?